# Mount bind mounts after local filesystem mount

Tags: mount, nfsv4

I want the bind mounts to be mounted only after the physical filesystems have been mounted. This is even more important because one of the filesystems has to be mounted manually as it's LUKS encrypted with a password.

This is my idea of achieving this:

```
# Filesystem mounts
# This one is mounted automatically since it's using a key
/dev/mapper/sandssd_crypt /mnt/drive1 btrfs defaults,compress-force=zstd,space_cache,ssd,noatime,nofail 0 2
# This one needs to be mounted manually with a password
/dev/mapper/320gbhdd /mnt/drive2 ext4 defaults,noatime,nofail 0 2


# Bind mounts
#/mnt/drive1/files /srv/nfs/files none x-systemd.requires=/mnt/drive1,x-systemd.automount,bind 0 2
#/mnt/drive2/files /srv/nfs/files2 none x-systemd.requires=/mnt/drive2,x-systemd.automount,bind 0 2
```

Is this a good approach to achieve it with `x-systemd.requires=` or won't it work the way I want it to?

Comment: what approach? if you were me, can you know that?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to spawn a script from rc.local that loops and looks for the mounts you want to bind. When it sees them, it can bind to them and exit.

Linux used to be simple, and much more easily made to work like you want it to work before the borg of systemd encircled the solar system...sigh.